# Unicode interpretation on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unicode

On one machine I see this (expected):

```
echo €€€€€€€€€€€ > foo
wc -m foo
12 foo
wc -c foo
34 foo
```

So that's 11 Euro signs.

On the problem machine, we see this:

```
echo €€€€€€€€€€€ > foo
wc -m foo
35 foo
wc -c foo
103 foo
```

Both machines are Linux (RHEL)

What could cause this?

LANG is set to en_US.UTF-8 on both machines.

The good box:
locale

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The problem box:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What is the output of "locale" and "localectl" commands in both machines?

Comment: Added locale to op - localectl doesn't exist. Boxes are 6.6 and 6.9.

Comment: Could you do `od -x foo`? It seems a copy paste problem (or your keyboard driver inserts some uneccessary characters)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yes you're correct. Changing the SSH client configuration for the problem box had resolved the oddities.